# How do I consume a WS-Security service in WCF over HTTPS?

Tags: wcf, soap, ws-security

I'm trying to consume a WS-Security enabled service with WCF.  Authentication works using a UsernameToken.  I'm not very knowledgeable with WCF web service clients, but I think my configuration below works for regular HTTP communication.  I (mostly) used [this guide](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CGQQFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/7/7/e77e5b26-1a19-49b7-b90c-d0847882e848/WCF%2520and%2520WS-Security%2520updated.doc&ei=J_3YT_A1k6LyBPfdpecD&usg=AFQjCNEakEb51jo0NdI-ViRSgMgV45FZWQ) to configure it.  The main difference is that I used the VS2010 "Add Service Reference" UI instead of a command prompt.

My problem is that I need to do this over HTTPS.  When I use `<security mode="Message">` in my app.config, I believe my soap envelope contains the needed WS-Security headers.  I can't tell for sure because I can't get logging to work.  However, I get the following error: `The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.  Parameter name: via`.

Below are the contents of my app.config file, as well as a sample of my client code.

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Omitted" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://omitted.com/service" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Omitted" contract="Omitted.Omitted" name="Omitted" />
</client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

```
var service = new OmittedClient();
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";    
var response = service.DoSomething(new DoSomethingRequest());
```

Comment: HTTPS is a transport security mode.

Comment: Yes, but how do I also use message security?  Is message security what I need for using UsernameToken?

Comment: Use the TransportWithMessageCredential mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to 500 - Internal Server error for helping me figure it out.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Generate a proxy using Visual Studio/WCF.
2. Change the security mode to TransportWithmessageCredential.
3. Use the following code to specify a username/password.

```
    var client = new WebServiceClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "USERNAME";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "PASSWORD";
```

1. If you get a response back, but WCF complains when processing it, there might be a timestamp missing from the response.  If that's the case, try this to fix it.

```
    // WCF complains about a missing timestamp (http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages)
    var elements = service.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
    elements.Find().IncludeTimestamp = false;
    service.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
```

Comment: Excuse the mess - Markdown seems to be having trouble with my post.